# Nil data returned when copying "working" json data to new struc array

Tags: swift

Weird.  I swear this was working but then it just stopped working .. or ...  Please ignore the i+i ,I will clean this up...

I don't have a clue why but  `myrecords?[i].title` is returning nil. The `json.releases[i].date_adde` is working fine and full of data. I can "print" it and get a result. but when I go to copy it to the myrecords it is returning nil.

I download the data from JSON, that works fine. then I try to copy the data to a struc array I can get to in other parts of my app and now my myrecords data is empty.  what the heck am I doing wrong?

```
import Foundation

var numberOfRecords : Int = 0


struct routine {
    var dateadded : String
    var title : String
    var artist : String
    var year : Int
    var recordlabel : String
}

var myrecords: [routine]?


//-------------------------------------------------------------

struct Response: Codable {
    var pagination: MyResult
    var releases: [MyReleases]
}

public struct MyResult: Codable {
    var page: Int
    var per_page: Int
    var items: Int
}

public struct MyReleases: Codable {
    var date_added: String
    var basic_information: BasicInformation
}

public struct BasicInformation: Codable {
    var title: String
    var year: Int
    var artists : [Artist]
    var labels: [Label]
}

public struct Artist: Codable {
    var name: String
}

public struct Label: Codable {
    var name: String
}

let url = "https://api.discogs.com/users/douglasbrown/collection/folders/0/releases?callback=&sort=added&sort_order=desc&per_page=1000"



public func getData(from url: String) {
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("something went wrong")
            return
        }
        //HAVE DATA
        var result: Response?
        do {
            result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            print("Converion Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        guard let json = result else {
            return
        }
        

        numberOfRecords = json.pagination.items
    
        var i: Int
        i = -1
        for _ in json.releases {
            i = i + 1
    
            myrecords?[i].dateadded = json.releases[i].date_added
            myrecords?[i].title = json.releases[i].basic_information.title
            myrecords?[i].artist = json.releases[i].basic_information.artists[0].name
            myrecords?[i].year = json.releases[i].basic_information.year
            myrecords?[i].recordlabel = json.releases[i].basic_information.labels[0].name
            
            print(">>>>>>\(myrecords?[i].dateadded)")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
    
}
```

Comment: You never initialize myrecords so it’s nil.

Comment: A follow up on my previous comment, why is this property declared to be optional? Is this a design solution or just a bad habit, because if it wasn’t declared optional you would have gotten an error that had helped you solve this. If it is meant to be optional then initialize it, `myrecords = []`, in getData just before the loop and otherwise initialize it when you declare it, `var myrecords = [routine]()`

Comment: And try to follow swift naming conventions for types and variables, it should be `Routine` and `myRecords`

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson.  Yes, bad habit or more like, I'm learning :( I truly thank you!   I did as you recommended and now I'm getting '"Index out of range"'. any ideas?   I can't Thank You enough.

Comment: Use `append` on the array instead of using an index

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Again, apologies for being totally new.. I'm trying :)  you mean, like the suggestion below?  i have some issues with that not working too.  what would you recommend the .append?  THANK YOU DEARLY! THANK YOU!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson for example, the example below tells me to remove the i but it is still in the json.releases ...   

man, I'm struggling. lol lol

Comment: You should read up in how to do for loops but I would do `for release in json.releases {...}` and then use the `release` object to create a `routine` object and append it inside the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232334/discussion-between-igel-community-and-joakim-danielson).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `myrecords` array.

Otherwise, you cannot use subscript like `myrecords[i]` when you don't know the capacity of array, it can be out of index.

First, initialize your array.

```
var myrecords: [routine]? = []
```

Second, append new element to array instead of using subscript

```
       for _ in json.releases {
        let newRecord = routine()

        newRecord.dateadded = json.releases[i].date_added
        newRecord.title = json.releases[i].basic_information.title
        newRecord.artist = json.releases[i].basic_information.artists[0].name
        newRecord.year = json.releases[i].basic_information.year
        newRecord.recordlabel = json.releases[i].basic_information.labels[0].name
        
        myrecords.append(newRecord)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! You were huge help in pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. :) THANK YOU All for pointing me in the right direction

```
struct Routine {
    var dateadded : String
    var title : String
    var artist : String
    var year : Int
    var recordlabel : String
}

var myRecords: [Routine] = []



  var i : Int
    i = -1
    for _ in json.releases {
        var newRecord = Routine.self(dateadded: "", title: "", artist: "", year: 0, recordlabel: "")
            i = i + 1
            newRecord.dateadded = json.releases[i].date_added
            newRecord.title = json.releases[i].basic_information.title
            newRecord.artist = json.releases[i].basic_information.artists[0].name
            newRecord.year = json.releases[i].basic_information.year
            newRecord.recordlabel = json.releases[i].basic_information.labels[0].name
                
            myRecords.append(newRecord)
       }
    print(">>>>\(myRecords[0].dateadded)")
```

I will clean up the bad code too but it works and that is good! :)